# Unable to mount hard disk even after disabling fast boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, mount, hard-drive

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 in dual boot with Windows 10 preview build. I have two hard disks, one on which Ubuntu and Windows are installed and the other containing all the data. I am not able to access the hard drive containing data on Ubuntu. I have already disabled fast boot.

I get the following error message :

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/yash/Yash: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/yash/Yash"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (625133566): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Comment: The `Failed to read last sector` looks pretty suspicious. Can you confirm that this hard-drive can be opened in Windows? If not, then the hard-drive is corrupted and will need to be recovered.

Comment: @Zzzach... The hard drive works perfectly fine on Windows.

Comment: fast googling suggests: 
win: chkdisk -f driveletter
lin : sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2

Comment: @czapa.ols Just a hint, but if you don't post an answer,  OP will not be able to award you the bounty :)

Comment: @czapa.ols: Could you please convert your (twice upvoted) comment to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast Googling suggests:

Windows:

```
chkdisk -f driveletter
```

Linux:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2
```

Comment: @Fabby and so he did :) +1